# Catel MVVM EventToCommand for WinRT

Tags: mvvm, catel

I am developing Windows store App using catel mvvm but couldn't find EventToCommand functionality for WinRT. Does anyone has any idea where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not available because behaviors are not available in WIN80 (WinRT). They will be available in WIN81, then Catel will support all behaviors as well.